# Python Nested Dictionnary to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionnary like this :

```
dict = {'A': {'0': aaa, '1': bbb, '2': ccc}, 'B': {'0': 0, '1': 6, '2': 0}, 'C': {'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3}}
```

How can I transform it into a dataframe so that the dataframe looks like this:

```
     A      B       C
0   aaa     0       1
1   bbb     6       2
2   ccc     0       3
```

I tried looking at the from_dict() function but could not find a way to transform it like this.

Any ideas what I could use?

Comment: Use `df = pd.DataFrame(d)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the nested dictionaries to dataframe using this:

`df = pd.DataFrame(dict)`